# C#: Mapping the IDataReader.GetTableSchema() and DbType Enumeration?

Tags: c#, database, database-schema, query-string, dbtype

So, I have the following: `"SELECT * FROM MyTable;"`

When I do the following I get the TableData back, which is useful, but still leaves some things unknown?

```
//CommandBehavior.KeyInfo seems to actually return the correct primary keys
// not so much with CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly.
IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo)

DataTable table = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

now, when iterating over my table I come across a column named "DataType" and it is either System.String or System.Byte[] or System.Int32, etc. But, this only tells me the .NET type to store, it doesn't tell me if, for example, a `System.Decimal` is the `DbType.Currency` or `DbType.Decimal`. So when I'm creating an IDataParameter, I'm not sure what to set for the DbType.

```
parameter.ColumnName = columnName;
parameter.DbType = DbType.Decimal; (or should it have been Currency?)
```

Basically, how can I get the table's real schema... or does it even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing in parameters for a stored procedure, or some sql text, no you do not need to specify the parameters data type. the SqlCommand will correctly assign the data type for you.

I believe the ability to assign the DBType on a parameter is if you want to overwrite what the system would choose for you.

use the

```
SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameterName", valueAsObject);
```

command

*edit* you are using the IDbCommand, not the SqlCommand. I know that both SqlCommand and Oracle command do not need you to specify the DbType, but I do not know if other frameworks do need you to explicitly set the DbType. here is a method to tranform a system.type to a DbType enum value:

```
Class DBTypeConversion
{
    private static String[,] DBTypeConversionKey = new String[,] 
    {
     {"BigInt","System.Int64"},
     {"Binary","System.Byte[]"},
     {"Bit","System.Boolean"},
     {"Char","System.String"},
     {"DateTime","System.DateTime"},
     {"Decimal","System.Decimal"},
     {"Float","System.Double"},
     {"Image","System.Byte[]"},
     {"Int","System.Int32"},
     {"Money","System.Decimal"},
     {"NChar","System.String"},
     {"NText","System.String"},
     {"NVarChar","System.String"},
     {"Real","System.Single"},
     {"SmallDateTime","System.DateTime"},
     {"SmallInt","System.Int16"},
     {"SmallMoney","System.Decimal"},
     {"Text","System.String"},
     {"Timestamp","System.DateTime"},
     {"TinyInt","System.Byte"},
     {"UniqueIdentifer","System.Guid"},
     {"VarBinary","System.Byte[]"},
     {"VarChar","System.String"},
     {"Variant","System.Object"}
    };


    public static SqlDbType SystemTypeToDbType( System.Type sourceType )
    {
    SqlDbType result;
    String SystemType = sourceType.ToString();
    String DBType = String.Empty;
    int keyCount = DBTypeConversionKey.GetLength(0);

    for(int i=0;i<keyCount;i++)
    {
    if(DBTypeConversionKey[i,1].Equals(SystemType)) DBType = DBTypeConversionKey[i,0];
    }

    if (DBType==String.Empty) DBType = "Variant";

    result = (SqlDbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), DBType);

    return result;
    }

    public static Type DbTypeToSystemType( SqlDbType sourceType )
    {
    Type result;
    String SystemType = String.Empty;
    String DBType = sourceType.ToString();
    int keyCount = DBTypeConversionKey.GetLength(0);

    for(int i=0;i<keyCount;i++)
    {
    if(DBTypeConversionKey[i,0].Equals(DBType)) SystemType = DBTypeConversionKey[i,1];
    }

    if (SystemType==String.Empty) SystemType = "System.Object";

    result = Type.GetType(SystemType);

    return result;
    }
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/c6f3ab91-2198-402a-9a18-66ce442333a6
hope this helps better clarify.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx

Comment: I'm not using SqlCommand. My type is of type `IDbCommand`. And in IDbCommand you can't do command.Parameters.AddWithValue(...); Only command.Parameters.Add() because the command.Parameters is of type IDataParameterCollection.

Comment: NB is somewhat correct. You don't need to set the DbType explicitly, just pass the value in. However, you're also correct. IDbCommand.Parameters does not have an AddWithValue method. See my answer below...

Comment: my bad! the interfaces do not specify that distinction. I do know that both the SqlCommand and the OracleCommand objects do not need the DbType defined. but... I do not know of other implementations, which might need them. I have updated my answer with the corresponding method.

Comment: @NB: That whole converter mapping thing won't solve anything because I'd still be wondering if I should map System.Decimal to DbType.Decimal or DbType.Currency. But, you're right. I'll let the driver determine what to map my System.Decimal to.

Comment: Ah, yeah the decimal data type is very confusing, since decimal within SQL Server defines a precision range (number of digits before and after the period), vs .net decimal is far more flexible with variable precision. I'd write a few boundary unit tests to make sure the .net framework is dealing with the precision as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
IDbCommand command = GetCommand(); //However you want to implement it.

IDbDataParameter param = command.CreateParameter();
//Or some other method that returns a parameter.

command.Parameters.Add(param);
param.Value = thevalue; //You're value here!
```

Sadly, you can't do it in one line if you use IDbCommand. You can't do something like `command.Parameters.Add(param).Value = thevalue;`

Also, you do **NOT** need to set the DbType of the parameter. The correct mapping is automagically done for you :)